# ASP.NET AJAX Auto-Complete using WebMethod?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, autocomplete

I'm trying to use an auto-complete, and it works fine if I call a function without a parameter in the web service:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<Script.Services.ScriptMethod()> _
Public Function GetCompanyNames2() As String()

    Dim db As New DataClassesDataContext

    Dim company = From c In db.CT_Companies
                      Where c.CompanyName.Contains("Airport")
                      Select c.CompanyName

    Return company.ToArray

End Function
```

If I try to call a function that takes a parameter, which I need to do so I can get the text entered by the user in the text box, it won't even hit the function at all, I put a break point on it and it never hits the break point:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<Script.Services.ScriptMethod()> _
Public Function GetCompanyNames(ByVal prefixTest As String) As String()

    Dim db As New DataClassesDataContext

    Dim company = From c In db.CT_Companies
                      Where c.CompanyName.Contains(prefixTest)
                      Select c.CompanyName

    Return company.ToArray

End Function
```

Does anybody know what's going on?

Here is the content from default.aspx:

```
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/AutoComplete.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" ID="autoComplete1" TargetControlID="txtCompanyName"
        ServicePath="~/AutoComplete.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCompanyNames" MinimumPrefixLength="1"
        EnableCaching="true" />
</div>
```

Comment: How are you calling these functions?

Comment: <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/AutoComplete.asmx" />
        </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" ID="autoComplete1" TargetControlID="txtCompanyName"
            ServicePath="~/AutoComplete.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetCompanyNames" MinimumPrefixLength="1"
            EnableCaching="true" />
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to rebuild your webservice project and refresh the web reference (the web service proxy) in your web project?

Comment: i have the asmx file in the project, I can call the functions in the web service, as long as they don't have parameters.  I even tried creating a project from scratch with a default page and a web service, same thing, but then I tried using c# and it works.  So only when I use vb does it give me an issue, but there's too much code in my project in the app_code folder to switch it all to c# and it won't let me have mixed files in their since they get compiled together.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too long after the fact to be useful but the parameter must be named *prefixText* and not *prefixTest* as you have here.